# California: loss of vacation time after conversion from PTO to FTO

Tags: employment, california

A few years ago, my employer implemented a flexible time off (FTO) policy where there's no predefined limit to the amount of time you can take off; you just need to get agreement from your manager before you take it. California employees who had previously accrued PTO time had that time "banked" to be paid out on termination. So far, so good.

HOWEVER, the new policy also included a provision that said that 80 hours would be deducted from your banked PTO time at the end of every year until the balance was zero. Here's the precise wording they used:

> Q: What is the FTO decrement provision?
>
> The decrement provision only applies to employees who transitioned to FTO from exception states with a PTO or a frozen PTO balance. Beginning in 2018, 80 hours of unused PTO will be deducted from this bank at the end of each year. For example, if you currently have 180 hours in your PTO bank and remain on the FTO plan, 80 hours will be deducted at the end of 2018, 80 hours will be deducted at the end of 2019, and the remaining 20 hours will expire at the end of 2020. You are expected to take a reasonable amount of time off each year – at least the amount to be deducted – for rest, relaxation, rejuvenation, and occasional sick days.

My main question is whether there's anything in California law that could be used to justify this "decrement provision". My understanding was that in California, earned vacation time is treated similarly to wages, in that an employer can't simply decide to take it away once it's been earned.

A secondary question is whether there's realistically anything I can do if they don't back down from their position. I'm being laid off, and in order to get my severance package, which is worth more than the vacation time I'd be shorted, I need to sign an agreement that says I won't sue them.

Comment: Are they saying you're going to lose it? The decrement plan, 2 things: 1. do they pay you the 80 hours they're decrementing? 2. If you use 80 through the years, do they still decrement another 80 hours?

Comment: @mkennedy 1. They do not pay for the hours as they're deducted. 2. They do not track the FTO time used; 80 hours is deducted every year regardless of how much time off you've taken.